# No aparecen las imágenes en mi plantilla de newsletter al enviar el correo

Tags: html, asp.net, email

comunidad de Stack Overflow. Tengo un pequeño problema.

Tengo una plantilla en HTML con marcadores, estos marcadores los sustituyo por información pertinente de a quien va dirigido el correo.

Al enviar el correo, sí me respeta el diseño de la plantilla, pero las imágenes no me aparecen. ¿Cuál puede ser el problema? Trabajo en ASP.NET.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour] para aprender sobre el funcionamiento del sitio y a leer [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). A tu pregunta le falta más información, por ejemplo el fragmento de código con el que construyes el correo, si la imagen va inline o está alojada en algún servidor, etc.. Lee el artículo y luego edita tu pregunta para mejorar tus probabilidades de obtener buenas respuestas. Además dices que trabajas con asp.net pero has utilizado la etiqueta asp, quizás por eso no ha recibido atención tu pregunta.

Comment: ¿Como has incluido tu imagen? Pon el codigo html para que podamos verlo.